# Django. Override the html format of a FileField field in the change page via ModelAdmin

Tags: django

This is my sample code (and see the screenshot):

models.py

```
class User(models.Model):

    # the variable to take the inputs
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user_avatar = models.FileField(upload_to = 'images/%Y%m%d')
```

admin.py

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    exclude = ('user_avatar',)  
    readonly_fields = ('avatar_readonly',)  

    def avatar_readonly(self, instance):
        value_link = "/mediafileupdown/download/" + str(instance.id)
        value_desc = str(instance.user_avatar.name)
        return format_html('<a href="{}">{}</a>', value_link, value_desc)  
    avatar_readonly.short_description = "User avatar (read only)"
    avatar_readonly.allow_tags=True
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMWkM.png)

The problem is: i'd like obtain the 'Currently' user_avatar's link (that's a  models.FileField field) via the my 'download' views and not as simple url. I can do that if the field is in the 'readonly_fields' list and so I can overide the html format ... in that case, on the change page, the 'avatar_readonly' link is redirected to the my 'download' view. 
The question is: how can I get the same result (overide the html format) in a FileField (like my 'user_avatar') when is not in the readonly_fileds list?

Sorry for my english and many Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [formfield_overrides](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides) to modify the AdminFileWidget. This AdminFileWidget can display images and mp4 files, but you can use only for images omitting the `if file_name[-4:] == '.mp4':`
 part.

```
from django.db.models.fields.files import FileField
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AdminFileWidget


class AdminMediaWidget(AdminFileWidget):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        output = []
        if value and getattr(value, "url", None):
            image_url = value.url
            file_name = str(value)
            if file_name[-4:] == '.mp4':
                output.append('<video width="320" height="240" controls>'
                              '<source src="{0}" type="video/mp4">'
                              'Your browser does not support the video tag.'
                              '</video>'.format(image_url))
            else:
                output.append('<a href="{0}" target="_blank">'
                              '<img height=200 src="{1}" alt="{2}" />'
                              '</a>'.format(image_url, image_url, file_name))

        output.append(super(AdminFileWidget, self).render(name, value, attrs))
        return mark_safe(''.join(output))


class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        FileField: {'widget': AdminMediaWidget},
    }

    exclude = ('user_avatar',)  
    readonly_fields = ('avatar_readonly',)  

    def avatar_readonly(self, instance):
        value_link = "/mediafileupdown/download/" + str(instance.id)
        value_desc = str(instance.user_avatar.name)
        return format_html('<a href="{}">{}</a>', value_link, value_desc)  
    avatar_readonly.short_description = "User avatar (read only)"
    avatar_readonly.allow_tags=True
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: If it helped you, please mark the response as accepted, @ssboy :). http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Many Thanks fo the reply. But how can I interacting with my 'download' view in a widget class? To interact, I need (like in avatar_readonly definition) of an istance of User into the AdminMediaWidget class . I have to obtain the result like that one obtained in  avatar_readonly where value_link is an url composed by the view path's and the id of the current user. I have also tryed to put something like 
`output.append('<a href="{}"></a>'.format('{% url "mediafileupdown:download" user.id %}')) ` but without success.

Comment: OK! I have found the solution: The instance of Fields is in value : `value.instance.id` Thanks.