# How to change the path in the change page of the admin django panel

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-urls

All the files that I upload in the django admin panel are stored in a FTP server, no files are stored locally.

[An example of how the change page looks after the file has been uploaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnS9S.png)

I'd like to know how to change that circled href, so that when I click on it the path corresponds to the ftp path + the uploaded file's name.

So it currently links to "http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/basic_app/software/6/change/profile_pics/file_name", but it should link to something like "ftp://:@:/folder/file_name", so that when it's clicked it opens the file on the FTP server.

Is this solvable by altering a url path somewhere, or do I have to do a template override of these pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can override AdminFileWidget in admin.py (source :[Django. Override the html format of a FileField field in the change page via ModelAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42971599/django-override-the-html-format-of-a-filefield-field-in-the-change-page-via-mod))

Try this :

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

class AdminMediaWidget(AdminFileWidget):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None,renderer=None):
        output = []
        if value and getattr(value, "url", None):
            image_url = value.url
            output.append('Real ftp link : <a href="ftp://myftp/{0}">{1}</a>'.format(image_url, image_url))

        output.append(super(AdminFileWidget, self).render(name, value, attrs))
        return mark_safe(''.join(output))


class FileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        FileField: {'widget': AdminMediaWidget},
    }


admin.site.register(MyModelFile,FileAdmin)
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. But the link is now above the "currently", so the old link is still there below the "real ftp link", so there are now two links there. Isn't there a way to delete the "currently" part?

Comment: I also came upon with a solution that adds a button on top of the change page with the link you want, although that's not really what i want in this case. Just in case anyone that sees this is interested in that feature I'll add the code below.

Add this lines to admin.py

class FileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def view_on_site(self, obj):
        return 'ftp://' + str(obj.file)

admin.site.register(MyModelFile, FileAdmin)

Comment: if you want to delete currently + change option => remove this line :output.append(super(AdminFileWidget, self).render(name, value, attrs))

Comment: Thank you Eric! That's the answer I was looking for.